# Is it simple or is it hard?

Tags: code-golf, string

For your hard thing to do, you must make a thing for a computer to do that finds out if some words are explained in a simple way. Something is explained in a simple way if it only uses the ten hundred most used words. If not, it is explained in a hard way. This can be a full computer thing or part of a computer thing. (full program or function)

There is a thing for a computer to read that has all of the ten hundred words in it with a space between each word. The name of the thing for the computer to read is called 'most used.txt'. You can take this thing from [this computer place](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2sM8IORrbL3RVpJWTZNUy1rOFU/view?usp=sharing).

The person who uses the computer thing will enter some words. (This can be from STDIN, function arguments or command line arguments) The computer must say something like a true if the words are simple and something like a not true if it is hard. ([truthy-falsy](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2190/interpretation-of-truthy-falsey)) The person who makes the shortest thing for the computer to do is the best. The things that every person knows are bad are bad. ([standard loopholes apply](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default))

---

More stuff to know about how the computer thing works:

- It doesn't matter if the words are BIG or little.
- The pictures that make what the word meaning easier to know (punctuation) don't matter. So if the person who uses the computer thing says "dont" it isn't a different word than the word "don't". Numbers and other pictures also don't matter. So if the person says "HE$$ll9o" the computer should read it like "hello"
- The little lines between words (dashes) work the same way as spaces. So the word "up-goer-five" is the same as the words "up goer five".

---

More stuff to know about making words like this:

https://xkcd.com/1133/

http://splasho.com/upgoer5/#

Comment: So check the computer thing user's words to the big word thing to see if all the words in the little word thing are in the big word thing?

Comment: @Geobits couldn't have said it better myself.

Comment: Can the words we check have many lines or can only space come between them?

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I found this exceptionally difficult to read.

Comment: @PeterTaylor The words that the person says, or the big words the computer reads?

Comment: The words that the person says.

Comment: (I'm done talking in up-goer-five) I don't have any objection to having the input on multiple lines, but I don't see how since it would be taken from STDIN followed by an enter,

Comment: You don't mention STDIN in the spec, and it's not the only acceptable default. "types some words and hits the enter thing" could mean command line arguments, etc. The simple-talk is funny, but it helps to be clear, and it's not very conducive to that.

Comment: It might be better to give a synopsis in simple-talk, followed by an actual spec in "real" English.

Comment: Does the dictionary have to be read from a file? That might downright exclude a couple of languages.

Comment: You should have had a penalty for every word used which is hard in the program

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## CJam, 41 bytes

```
q"file:///most used.txt"g]{el_euS--S%}/-!
```

This makes the rather unclean assumption that `most used.txt` is in the root directory, since CJam cannot handle relative paths.

Alternatively, we have the following web-based solutions (78 and 29 bytes):

```
q"https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B2sM8IORrbL3RVpJWTZNUy1rOFU"g]{el_euS--S%}/-!
```

```
q"j.mp/-o_O"g]{el_euS--S%}/-!
```

The "proper" way of doing this in CJam would be reading both inputs from STDIN (input on the first line, dictionary on the second), which is possible in 18 bytes:

```
qN%{el_euS--S%}/-!
```

You can try the last version in the [CJam interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=qN%25%7Bel_euS--S%25%7D%2F-!&input=ten%20hundred%0Athe%20I%20to%20and%20a%20of%20was%20he%20you%20it%20in%20her%20she%20that%20my%20his%20me%20on%20with%20at%20as%20had%20for%20but%20him%20said%20be%20up%20out%20look%20so%20have%20what%20not%20just%20like%20go%20they%20is%20this%20from%20all%20we%20were%20back%20do%20one%20about%20know%20if%20when%20get%20then%20into%20would%20no%20there%20I'm%20could%20don't%20ask%20down%20time%20didn't%20want%20eye%20them%20over%20your%20are%20or%20been%20now%20an%20by%20think%20see%20hand%20it's%20say%20how%20around%20head%20did%20well%20before%20off%20who%20more%20even%20turn%20come%20smile%20way%20really%20can%20face%20other%20some%20right%20their%20only%20walk%20make%20got%20try%20something%20room%20again%20thing%20after%20still%20thought%20door%20here%20too%20little%20because%20why%20away%20let%20take%20two%20start%20good%20where%20never%20through%20day%20much%20tell%20wasn't%20girl%20feel%20oh%20you're%20call%20talk%20will%20long%20than%20us%20made%20friend%20knew%20open%20need%20first%20which%20people%20that's%20went%20sure%20seem%20stop%20voice%20very%20felt%20took%20our%20pull%20laugh%20man%20okay%20close%20any%20came%20told%20love%20watch%20arm%20anything%20I'll%20though%20put%20left%20work%20guy%20hair%20next%20couldn't%20yeah%20while%20mean%20home%20few%20saw%20place%20school%20help%20wait%20late%20year%20can't%20house%20happen%20last%20always%20move%20old%20night%20nod%20life%20give%20sit%20stare%20sat%20should%20moment%20another%20behind%20side%20sound%20once%20find%20toward%20boy%20ever%20nothing%20front%20mother%20name%20am%20since%20reply%20he's%20myself%20leave%20bed%20new%20car%20use%20mind%20maybe%20has%20heard%20answer%20minute%20yes%20until%20both%20found%20end%20small%20I'd%20word%20someone%20same%20enough%20began%20run%20bit%20sigh%20each%20those%20almost%20against%20everything%20most%20thank%20wouldn't%20mom%20better%20play%20I've%20own%20every%20hard%20remember%20three%20stood%20live%20stand%20second%20sorry%20keep%20finally%20point%20gave%20already%20actually%20probably%20himself%20big%20everyone%20guess%20lot%20step%20hey%20hear%20light%20quickly%20dad%20kiss%20black%20pick%20else%20soon%20shoulder%20table%20best%20without%20notice%20stay%20care%20phone%20reach%20realize%20follow%20decide%20kind%20she's%20grab%20he'd%20show%20inside%20suddenly%20father%20rest%20herself%20grin%20hour%20hope%20also%20body%20might%20hadn't%20floor%20its%20continue%20ran%20across%20hold%20cry%20half%20pretty%20great%20course%20mouth%20class%20kid%20miss%20wonder%20morning%20least%20nice%20dark%20slowly%20done%20change%20doesn't%20together%20yet%20question%20anyway%20bad%20blue%20believe%20week%20God%20lip%20Mr.%20sleep%20fine%20what's%20family%20many%20worry%20roll%20parents%20under%20surprise%20water%20onto%20we're%20glance%20wall%20between%20seen%20read%20window%20idea%20white%20push%20feet%20must%20such%20seat%20set%20please%20red%20brother%20these%20whole%20lean%20part%20person%20slightly%20pass%20shook%20fact%20wrong%20gone%20far%20hit%20finger%20quite%20hate%20meet%20finish%20heart%20book%20past%20kill%20reason%20anyone%20figure%20top%20along%20world%20she'd%20high%20shirt%20does%20today%20young%20held%20outside%20listen%20whisper%20won't%20happy%20ground%20deep%20drop%20shrug%20dress%20fell%20there's%20yell%20breath%20air%20tear%20sister%20chair%20kitchen%20matter%20hurt%20fall%20wear%20isn't%20woman%20eat%20lie%20hell%20suppose%20cover%20couple%20large%20either%20five%20leg%20jump%20die%20return%20able%20bag%20alone%20shut%20stuff%20short%20ready%20understand%20kept%20plan%20raise%20street%20different%20problem%20break%20line%20early%20cut%20cold%20paper%20scream%20instead%20stupid%20silence%20tree%20caught%20ear%20food%20full%20four%20cause%20fuck%20explain%20expect%20fight%20exactly%20sort%20completely%20men%20dance%20met%20story%20whatever%20build%20speak%20glass%20pain%20check%20glare%20corner%20Mrs.%20chest%20hot%20rather%20month%20real%20touch%20park%20bring%20they're%20drink%20ago%20force%20you've%20fast%20lost%20attention%20wish%20mark%20wave%20shout%20fill%20begin%20baby%20interest%20money%20fun%20green%20however%20cheek%20mine%20clear%20brown%20forward%20near%20picture%20may%20cool%20drive%20hug%20shake%20sense%20alright%20you'll%20dream%20hang%20clothes%20act%20become%20manage%20meant%20game%20ignore%20stair%20taken%20party%20add%20sometimes%20job%20ten%20shot%20date%20quiet%20gaze%20group%20loud%20straight%20dead%20neck%20beside%20pause%20number%20conversation%20chance%20we'll%20rose%20quietly%20town%20blood%20color%20desk%20dinner%20hall%20horse%20music%20brought%20piece%20anymore%20beautiful%20order%20fire%20office%20true%20although%20warm%20easy%20enter%20perfect%20mutter%20softly%20cross%20shock%20smirk%20damn%20soft%20stomach%20snap%20spoke%20tire%20box%20catch%20skin%20teacher%20middle%20note%20yourself%20haven't%20lunch%20tomorrow%20breathe%20clean%20except%20appear%20lock%20knock%20bathroom%20movie%20agree%20offer%20kick%20form%20confuse%20lay%20less%20calm%20slip%20weren't%20sign%20dog%20lift%20immediately%20arrive%20deal%20tonight%20usually%20case%20frown%20shop%20scare%20promise%20mum%20couch%20pay%20state%20shit%20wrap%20pocket%20hello%20free%20huge%20ride%20bother%20land%20known%20especially%20expression%20carry%20ring%20spot%20allow%20several%20aren't%20during%20empty%20lady%20eyebrow%20strange%20coffee%20road%20threw%20wide%20bus%20forget%20gotten%20smell%20fear%20press%20boyfriend%20blonde%20throw%20round%20sun%20tall%20glad%20age%20write%20upon%20hide%20became%20crowd%20rain%20save%20trouble%20annoy%20nose%20weird%20death%20beat%20tone%20trip%20six%20control%20nearly%20consider%20gonna%20join%20learn%20above%20hi%20obviously%20entire%20direction%20foot%20angry%20power%20strong%20quick%20doctor%20edge%20song%20asleep%20twenty%20barely%20remain%20child%20enjoy%20gun%20slow%20city%20broke%20key%20lead%20throat%20normal%20you'd%20somewhere%20wake%20pair%20sky%20funny%20business%20student%20giggle%20bright%20admit%20jeans%20given%20children%20store%20sweet%20low%20climb%20rub%20apartment%20knee%20shoe%20attack%20bedroom%20joke%20spent%20situation%20stuck%20gently%20possible%20cell%20mention%20silent%20definitely%20rush%20hung%20brush%20perhaps%20groan%20ass%20rock%20card%20lose%20blush%20besides%20crazy%20type%20bore%20afraid%20chase%20respond%20marry%20remind%20pack%20daughter%20serious%20girlfriend%20mad%20somehow%20buy%20sent%20tight%20simply%20trust%20imagine%20wind%20chuckle%20bar%20pink%20shove%20ball%20sight%20drag%20they'd%20human%20truth%20share%20area%20concern%20shouldn't%20team%20escape%20mumble%20often%20search%20apparently%20attempt%20son%20within%20band%20cute%20led%20memory%20anger%20fly%20paint%20bottle%20busy%20comment%20exclaim%20avoid%20grow%20grey%20mirror%20gasp%20hallway%20dear%20star%20sick%20cat%20counter%20interrupt%20none%20blink%20spend%20usual%20worse%20locker%20important%20favorite%20grip%20TV%20ice%20pretend%20settle%20amaze%20pop%20disappear%20carefully%20train%20stick%20guard%20teeth%20flash%20uncle%20send%20doubt%20visit%20nervous%20excite%20approach%20excuse%20fit%20noise%20study%20letter%20police%20eventually%20burn%20field%20hospital%20tie%20summer%20huh%20shift%20self%20hurry%20greet%20wife%20position%20we've%20wipe%20heavy%20slam%20broken%20complete%20space%20brain%20tiny%20pants%20ah%20punch%20shower%20tongue%20afternoon%20seriously%20cup%20further%20race%20recognize%20computer%20rang%20safe%20jacket%20bottom%20hundred%20relax%20sudden%20wow%20college%20flip%20mood%20track%20crack%20block%20handle%20themselves%20drove%20seven%20struggle%20whether%20ahead%20sad%20dry%20women%20focus%20repeat%20thick%20relationship%20jerk%20present%20suck%20bell%20surround%20evening%20bite%20single%20fault%20shadow%20wood%20easily%20woke%20smoke%20draw%20suggest%20wet%20accept%20third%20totally%20wore%20breakfast%20trail%20animal%20warn%20aunt%20sir%20piss%20burst%20match%20fix%20practically). (permalink tested in Chrome)

#### Examples

```
$ cjam <(echo 'q"file:///most used.txt"g]{el_euS--S%}/-!') <<< 'ten hundred'; echo
1
$ cjam <(echo 'q"file:///most used.txt"g]{el_euS--S%}/-!') <<< 'thousand'; echo
0
```

Comment: You could use tinyurl on the Drive url to make it shorter

Comment: @M.I.Wright Figured it out. That and uploading the file to Pastebin saved 12 bytes. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

## R, 106 bytes

Is not sure if is understand challenge because is has hard time reading.

```r
function(s){u=toupper;all(strsplit(gsub("[^A-Z -']","",u(s)),"[ -]")[[1]]%in%u(scan("most used.txt","")))}
```

This creates an unnamed part of a computer thing that accepts a string and returns something like a true or like a not true.

Ungolfed + explanation:

```r
partOfAComputerThing <- function(s) {
    # Remove everything but letters, spaces, dashes, and single quotes
    s <- gsub("[^A-Z -']", "", toupper(s))

    # Split s into a vector on spaces/dashes
    v <- strsplit(s, "[ -]")[[1]]

    # Read the file of words (assumed to reside in the current directory)
    m <- scan("most used.txt", "")

    # Determine if all words in the input are in the file
    all(v %in% toupper(m))
}
```

Thanks to Dennis for inspiration thing.

Comment: Something like `part-of-a-computer-thing(s){...}` should be worth bonus points.

Comment: @Dennis: How's this? :)

Comment: Much better!​​​

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3, 148 bytes

```
import re
print(all(i in open("most used.txt").read().lower().split(' ')for i in re.sub("[^a-z ']+","",input().replace("-"," ").lower()).split(" ")))
```

Outputs `True` and `False`

### Examples

```
Input:  Don't
Output: True

Input:  The poison air he's breathing has a dirty smell of dying
Output: False

Input:  Who let the dogs out?
Output: False
```

Comment: Will this handle an input of `don't` correctly?

Comment: @AlexA. It returns `True`. Is that correct?

Comment: Any reason you split `most used.txt` by new lines? I'm not 100% sure on how this works, but I imagine you're trying to split it into each individual word in the file?

Comment: @DeadChex What is the supplied text file separated by? I can't access it because it keeps throwing an SSL error.

Comment: and for me on Python 3.4.1 running it an typing in `don't` prints `False` same with `Who let the dogs out?` actually.

Comment: The question states "There is a thing for a computer to read that has all of the ten hundred words in it with a space between each word"

Comment: As for the SSL error, Drive will happily serve it over http http://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B2sM8IORrbL3RVpJWTZNUy1rOFU

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 35 bytes

```
!-Fm@LGcrXd\-bZ),zs'"most used.txt
```

Tests, where the above is the file `common.pyth`

```
$ pyth common.pyth <<< 'I can write this way too-hell99#0O.'
True
$ pyth common.pyth <<< 'But I get confused easily.'
False
```

Explanation:

```
!-Fm@LGcrXd\-bZ),zs'"most used.txt
   m            ,zs'"most used.txt    Map over input and input file:
         Xd\-b                        Replace hyphens with newlines.
        r     Z                       Cast to lower case.
       c       )                      Split on whitespace.
    @LG                               Remove non-alphabetic characters.
 -F                                   Setwise difference - remove anything in
                                      the text file from the input.
!                                     Logical negation.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 69 bytes

Assumes that the file is in the current directory.

```apl
s←819⌶' '(1↓¨,⊂⍨⊣=,)'[- ]' '\W'⎕R' ' ''
∧/(s⍞)∊s⊃⎕NGET'most used.txt'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/apl-dyalog#fZixrjU3FYX7PIW7k0ghKB0UlBClCEIoQAEUnhnPjP8zYw@2585/UoIUooggJERLQ0GegAfgUe6LhG9tnwTRUPz3v3fOHHt777XXWtu3PdfmzhqmD9rbdnv9899@@rNffPr61de3tgb3sWvZ@TQ57/LsLl8dDx/5dLG5mPijuMqTtvrm9odbY3V7cDm5K7bV8VDf8JObc3HD2Xhhd9XHyQ3BnYfLPNpyvruaee0luEsLpdzcm5OotngPbsksHx6OpZvWn0vend82d/F6KMENfry7KbNrcH7QkveULxeJdw3JLaFpgUS8nOXK5zaxgx7x3Y9vt92N9mzK6XZTwFrsSq5FTjLFyZ5ePjUXHjpp2F1@4dxkoTjPGjpaYH1t6pMbHoozcaYQOBS5i@12qxyb/OiVkk8eroG0sDxn4CxDIEMsNSvo7Hb9EV5YtJ0lESCh1D1unJhVSuD4Dzey2exHvtWsDnqpxGW148ZCPnjp8tvd7d7yyAflYe8pwMWVrEwunkL2B35uWqhFImprPrXWlDmf5arlTEVaI4ohjB7IEOvDeYW0KcnapV2ZBXxp7JcnVYBvpqCEtbVoSTfx/n6Oq2s6OZiyDC@xbG4OYXN5VW5vN744qs5NR7gU05YJEqwl8MqhpgAYYiCZ9xQulw8VIQTQFgvoudbIJkfIx9YRqipcgULWk7UpD1hs@XAvOZJFQnwQwNZ00LtTdY9Tm3oFvbNpvhP5uGUO7pPyvyspQGfLgq5vbOfLrg97PkHXd5lkMQAdZuLK5e6WEzR4qpTC29YRaGl4BL8qckLeA3uuqurM6aq/3LGp3HVcc96oyXawKY24@Rb0xSJIaBE2rMLeoYxsnlz4jSqRMwWqiJPhJFGhLc5gI/K8spRKx280YV2tK3b2J2M@dZANgYNNvEruq@E4J0Ka9bDlyxc6Oz@c1VtfURZoWFbY@wJJSfMkPup7JRxgdA2qzP6oYZtJkXhgoIqq6cihdJZdG@z@MehYIiHt5FOFAPTZaQmo7kxglwjgntmiEzjqLhRRi0mpn6wBxBVVoYRkxRnCQrLLSfsqC2THBS@IrlbtzUjSWoX/dbpnhe25EHnvzGLpJ2cs2NRLVOyhrZV2OMW@yQmIooQ97ENvC4gCIFoxVIcm0qhhzPovF75xD@FQkq3vjwyTuUVp8htcMNGDYzv7ZyUPflBO427pHOLSd9WJlzPUClpVZxYUqyqTbCs0/O6M452vThDTPfLisIlZD566sFUVHGLvuFDc7KNCqdOiMG7ErU7iAOoOgHSs2rZYKsVa8TOwkrcNGpzCKBDdDU4dAUvxg4FBT8TgqePsnKYgLpu9QahoS36x8y1FMqRmXel/EoKSDJmU7HYmtMdKMm@isdgqrQZG0klUFNyPJXPQVS0xWmVY8ijU7sHKwVtnFuGP4630vuftO6S9Kz8XBRL@cknCAsglsKQMTJ4WrxxT6VQKRiCy8DyHznYtI0s6zCMo8ZwokluIQ2Q6UIBhO5XcLQZRSwh395Hh43CflA9Y@gmIrphK3uzRh4d46iGYc5hCot1BGVJTZyhUiO8osRpZBSmEFDEY1S6bV0de3tSoXVK0qh9CGBVOkyoyBS92ot2Os67ia@Auqa4i9KqMVR4dyoUKz0FKb3x@mGBkQLOJ2Q6JxEEZBSpDoPCrBFN8CBhpA1lFlL8ohTNAZWedemE90NpEBk1EGexxJCLhuYEAFjhUjrt0gyPUnl5bKC6nydkBXLQ86dqeIESX1ft1jaVZtXhNeoUg8SKUO8mzGCy3SBMlZaNyCoHBqBfSFXaMfSZVaSpsVNdyLvyq/puDiQLCqLo9TP6FNcQDPWhqyKq1i1DDk3tEWNhp90Yp60loczdAvBo7oK4shVL@gYwC3SjJcYi9RrMrAFk6uPkCDkO0msyimy0suK2dQKMqZoajt7ZfLEF04HqKMk7cCbVh@846hqnOVvdwqOriUC981VZUlCnOcxAAjZg2BFcnvRMjqxK9XMypJiOvh1ca68gLu1q/CXdsekTpzRaETq0Ks5gx0eFnkeYslZ5FAd2UzKcI6y3RQA38H0ahw77yFkxtskBFm@4kBA9C05DdyeCPNRIV0z3qK5Ox4YxCx6G4FyOAQwtTktEeyKbAALz5Sakf6LnoCY4tna52uqyzH1hSlxwih6FE8zLhYd03FTlGj9fFB46hG6AXgV422MSH4idjiUs437XIJQ2oRr1ztL5diAwBeMjsBiNKtofmZ5QNQgviysuORZyQyq5CjJtySaOiUGxvKp70COpvapVdfC7PQZjsuALlusrt1ZBMHrvttKA3vaUSivHkltT4EiiZRpkZcOqX7m6kYjyJS5LfBUnCP@t2ckDWpq7WsuLVvcmDU8dVJXdS48MBQWugKuq4g0ydwgwYNOsqBCWVCZVSyx6Gj3Sa7iIE5AGro5yKn8V@wQ5Q1Da2OOBoSsuwCWngFBWZgkaEmFTyVX1IS0gizhpHZdHQecQwmk00Kz8Ef7YIUBkWJmu8bvajYfpUCp8u8ZKBhK7wUMkMRCizALyf1vw1z4qpyxaJ4GzMBUBh8nuyTwXfXXpbk4d3jixTru2G/JYGkUetdzl@ibK5p2mi2ZFuQ11XVc1iRivbmeSCMqcAHk@e6ohRb41qe9lMmQgFw@SldHt5fVwQfhNS8UKejhtEZnwOyDR1pVnl2Gx84DiY/V1KcNhYZ9tjxOjMvMilMnDue5iit5b1xaA49bbqdvas53MwEgsYnEkRSehehLkxWp1s4rNGfAh0TT0UpTUk7CD@0IxA6UXFDdo1V03BfCVH2Izwkvk5aGGMtilEI3Y3MHmTXzU4@Zf5luGpajui9c@zTae9EfYDpG/iU@ZLNaEBWG5hVMrYOwNjucSL1lcYDD9kUHMtM511xC6@n61lTWLw4M/JCODC0jZ7Xa6rUoULmnALeWGi2egq0tLzIPbVdgg224CyaxKhs4OYpvF9CYNPCY@f1CQXg6Z0Tuo1SH2a9KIViljjWzNb2BBjExUmm6MrEvTkaWhWFvdIcDSZrNHl4SUyvWyGf8F24sdoPQrZaxBZiizwZYOquQPzraBkhLddmBYZVQ2z3SQ1TXzyVEWwwXV38hanh/SGcyxnMqvmxqj3ihrmHoTJnvZsNxKFIaITXKekPtheIsFDtFXvRrKYL8oDqao92zlJ@pa4LJLTTpJ@2sHaG/qn2tj1DKaojM1o8JJyWkBb3AeGkoEWgw9tEGPSNcoPEgRv1DZZq71R3MBR421kGrCUEYJEioc2NwBP1W8UWvanmpi0iitloKy1ipzdKr8z2K9QEK5G9jzLMnOyoiYfJRM2DONV6/rkWNq4@M9gzcehhuE8fi668IFhzRHSETbKWYsEm@sOu8AxVVdVQxEC7ELgCeLd96RrKBgYnKsibpbOGneNkJBoFUH4xTyxVh1Xzm42RkKm@5hVGBuE/Nr1ofhvJRjfd8pAsU6T/RNh8M8LsmMo34493btL3QKkchiZKKPwrtllX3QFcHTTLZaiPelvAdKGJFNnxaaBdcMdMwPKbHiztLMZYA13MI1ds5xVTbNb5WFbHM3u/EsmnYv6GV7VoAM101K@HiZHmiAmM5HNnKSVygYZExQzBuU8BOqk2llqDqXZ@FNuWKwsHuTt/cArSaln9jWaWNTcn/7SSbs0KtmIHSxev0uKjywvWZ@yIO6VQ1ONjEmaIlpOoaeBdIYITNWKmURUVFndxJ1Dcy9RFxKI7IvQwOm1OYuCQpLM3@b19ErujvOc7B7KVDNvCk83aM/BeJCtnaMMPCP9EZt0I2q4JLsy1Wb6JZ@mf6fguZiHvXRBQu/Ebr6C@bIrHnLZ/gUwbn7vtJG@85QkVDc1g52YcVN11RTmdQ0kRdV8q6EIopL6694t2XTdwW@@mAEPq28Tr7e7kjEvSRO0djmbPZfEeOJ74022hBu4gOadNHtBef7tc36mrpcMDHaftElld1kaiiKA2M/BJFxXllu/6CQXL3Q0BCOfafeRcO5pdAYBWmzeLjKrLjPlmnVdBFNTHF3umCKsKrhCUQJJ8gH74VikVP0yzljMBpbSFUo7SRsHlRw21X6zPzfdSnnNoZdCxyVp4r2M@Hb9pKFRT@KzSwny4UdzKIQgtOVmULjMkWkOMXctWKLKKYrhLxOj00hUtCEtPXWZuJtzmtG0g1yBYS11e@f1iz/O39TXz//ygw9/@Pqnf93c7d0PXz//67@/fv/1y9@/fvX165f/@NH7791@/T33Wz77za90v/5zfnM3ffef33@3vn719/dev/iyvn75B929f/TjT2//eyP/DXt8M78jgnnW9R3@0hUfheLXn@TnXbRdK/VrKcb6Kf@/z963S3yb3O1y2D8/1D29/y/A7N1@u68rvmoX9nHud826TKt2A/4ctkAccPedk@2q@oP/AA)

The first line defines a normalising and splitting-into-list-of-strings helper function, *s*:

`s←` *s* is
`819⌶` the lowercased
`' '(` result of the following function, with a space as left argument…
 `1↓¨` drop one from each of
 `,` the concatenation of the arguments
 `⊂⍨` cut before each element where
 `⊣` the left argument
 `=` is equal to
 `,` the concatenation of the arguments
`)` applied to
`'[- ]' '\W'⎕R' ' ''` the PCRE replacements dash/space→space, non-word-char→nothing

`∧/(`…`)` is it all-true that
 `s` the normalised and split
 `⍞` text input
`∊` are members of
`s` the normalised and split
`⊃` first element of
`⎕NGET'most used.txt'` the (content, encoding, newline-style) of the file

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES7), 161 bytes

```
s=>fetch("most used.txt").then(t=>t.text()).then(d=>alert(s.split(/[ -]/g).every(l=>d.split` `.map(w=>w.replace(/[\.']/,"")).includes(l.replace(/[^a-z]/g,"")))))
```

Anyone got a copy of the file online that I can use to create a working Snippet?

Comment: I guess that you can save 22 bytes by removing `then` and 7 bytes by removing `alert`.

Comment: Can you elaborate, @Titus? Each step of this returns a promise so the `then`s are required to execute subsequent code when they resolve.

Comment: I´m not that familiar with ES7; was thinking in the wrong direction. But maybe you can come up with something shorter if You reduce the input to all words not in the list? I doubt that PHP can really beat JS by almost 40%.

Comment: Oh, yeah, there's definitely room for improvement there; this was my last challenge of the day and I had brainache so I posted what I had so far to revisit tomorrow. Unfortunately, the chain of promises required just to get at the contents of a file puts JS at a disadvantage in these challenges against the likes of PHP but it's still better than the alternative of using XHR.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 101 bytes

```php
foreach(preg_split("#[^\w']+#",$argn)as$w)preg_match("#\b$w\b#i",end(file("most used.txt")))?:die(1);
```

takes input from STDIN, assumes single line dictionary
exits with `1` (error) for falsy, `0` (ok) for truthy. Run with `-R`.

Split input by non-word characters, loop through resulting array (words):
If word is in the dictionary, continue; else `exit(1)`.
implicit `exit(0)`.

or, simply put:

one word after another: If word is in the most used words, continue; else return 1.
return 0.

and: I could save two points if the most used words had a space each in front and at the end.

Answer (score -1):

## Java, 248 bytes

With the Phrase passed as an argument.

```java
void g(String s) throws Exception{String c=new java.util.Scanner(new java.io.File("most used.txt")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next(),x="false";for(String l:s.split(" "))if(c.contains(l.toLowerCase().replaceAll("![a-z]","")))x="true";System.out.print(x);}
```

input/output:

```java
g("was he")         --> "true"
g("was h!e")         --> "true"
g("delicious cake") --> "false"
```

Spaced and tabbed out:

```java
void g(String s) throws Exception{
    String c=new java.util.Scanner(new java.io.File("most used.txt")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next()
      ,x="false";
    for(String l:s.split(" "))
      if(c.contains(l.toLowerCase().replaceAll("![a-z]","")))
          x="true";
    System.out.print(x);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean *it's up to you to import what's needed*?

Comment: @Beta I use some of Java's utility classes that, if you were to put this function in a program you'd have to import (namely `java.io.*` and `java.util.*`), much like pythons import statement

Comment: Well you have to include these imports in your byte count. You aren't allowed to exclude import statements in Python, so you can't exclude them in Java

Comment: @BetaDecay Tweaked the program, no more imports needed