# The ten hundred most common words

Tags: code-golf, string, parsing

This question is written because ["Thing Explainer"](https://xkcd.com/thing-explainer/) is fun to read, and gave me an idea.

Write "stuff that makes computer do things" that reads/takes a set of letters, numbers and things like this `"#%|?` and returns `True / 1` if all words are part of [this set](http://xkcd.com/simplewriter/words.js?cache=6f3c4ed1c04dc0b6c30d46e2ea451210).

If all words are not part of that set, return the words that were not a part of it.

---

**[This website](http://xkcd.com/simplewriter/) can be considered correct in all cases.** The rules are written to follow the specs on that site.

---

## Examples:

**Truthy**:

*The code should return a truthy value if the entire text above the first horizontal line is pasted as input.*

The following lines should return a truthy value (input is separated by `###`)

```
This returns "Hello, World!"
###
tHiS rEtUrNs TrUe...
###
Thing Explainer is a book written by a man.
The man writes books with simple words.
###
This set of stuff "#!^{>7( must return true
```

**Falsey**:

In the following examples, input and output are separated by `***`. Different test cases are separated by `###`.

```
This code doesn't return "Hello, World!"
***
code
###
tHiS rEtUrN"s false...
***
s
false
```

**More detailed rules:**

- You can use [this](http://xkcd.com/simplewriter/) to test your code.
- Non-letters are interpreted as spaces by the code, except for words like `'wasn't'`. The words with apostrophes that returns `true` are included in the list

  - For instance: `foo123bar` should return `foo` and `bar`, since they are not part of the list, and `123` can be interpreted as spaces
- The input will only contain printable ASCII code points [10, 32-126].
- Words can contain mixed case letters. See second test case.
- The list of words

  - should be taken as input (STDIN, function argument or equivalent)
  - can be modified (words can be separated by newline, comma etc., and you might sort the list)
  - Note that you can not use [this](http://splasho.com/upgoer5/phpspellcheck/dictionaries/1000.dicin) list (it's not identical)
- The output can be on any format you like
- The output can be upper, lower or mixed case (optional)
- There shall be no symbols in the output

---

For the record, Jonathan Allan found a strange corner case:  the implementation on XKCD will actually ignore any letters after an apostrophe up to the next non-[A-Z][a-z]['] - for example `find's found`, and `find'qazxswedc found'` both return nothing, whereas `find'qazx.swedc found` returns `swedc`.

You can choose if you want to return nothing for `find'qazxswedc found'`, or return `qazxswedc`. Returning `qazx, swedc` for `find'qazx.swedc` is also OK.

Comment: [Extremely Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/53323/is-it-simple-or-is-it-hard)

Comment: I'm not *positive* it's a dupe though. Your challenge is slightly different, since you need to return the non-simple words. And, in your favor, you actually have a normal spec written in everyday English. http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/53323/is-it-simple-or-is-it-hard#comment127413_53323

Comment: For a statically typed language that cannot express a return type of `Boolean` or `Array<String>`, would returning an empty array/list be permissible?

Comment: @CAD97 for the case where all words are simple? You can select how you want to display the truthy value, it can be an integer/string `1`. An empty output is not permissible.

Comment: I'm confused by the new explanation of rules for the `find'qazxswedc` input. Are we or are we not supposed to split on apostrophes? For example, `isn't` returns `true` (it's in the list), but `isn` returns `isn`, since that's not on the list. From that logic, I went with "don't split on apostrophes" and so `find'qazxswedc found` returns `find'qazxswedc`.

Comment: Note that the "official" word set from XKCD contains non ASCII characters - this apostrophe ’ code point 8217

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### PowerShell v3+, <s>105</s> 92 bytes

```
param($a,$b)$x=@();-split($b-replace"[^a-zA-Z']",' ')|%{if($_-notin$a){$x+=$_}};($x,1)[!$x]
```

Takes simple words like `$a`, and words like `$b`. Makes helper `$x`. Take each word in `$b` and get rid of any bad not letters, then check each one `|{...}`. If that word is not in `$a`, then we add it to `$x`. At the end, we choose `$x` or `1` by not `$x`. That is sent out, either `words` or `1`.

#### Some words to try

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> ('This returns "Hello, World!"','tHiS rEtUrNs TrUe...','Thing Explainer is a book written by a man.
The man writes books with simple words.','This set of stuff "¤!^¤>7\ must return true'|%{"$_";(.\ten-hundred-most-common-words.ps1 (gc .\ten-hundred-most-common-words.txt) $_)})-join"`n###`n"
This returns "Hello, World!"
###
1
###
tHiS rEtUrNs TrUe...
###
1
###
Thing Explainer is a book written by a man.
The man writes books with simple words.
###
1
###
This set of stuff "¤!^¤>7\ must return true
###
1

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> ("This code doesn't returns Hello, World!",'tHiS rEtUrN"s false...'|%{"$_`n***`n"+(.\ten-hundred-most-common-words.ps1 (gc .\ten-hundred-most-common-words.txt) $_)})-join"`n###`n"
This code doesn't returns Hello, World!
***
code
###
tHiS rEtUrN"s false...
***
s false
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python, 93 bytes

```python
import re
lambda w,s:[w for w in re.sub("[^'\w]|\d|_",' ',w).split()if w.lower()not in s]or 1
```

All test cases are at **[ideone](http://ideone.com/UZdHg2)**

Preprocessing of the list is to split on `|` and put it in a `set` (which I imagine is fine if pre-sorting is allowed). Input words as `w` and the set as `s`.

If that's not allowed this becomes 98 bytes with `not in s` becoming `not in set(s)`.

We could preprocess it to have all permutations of upper and lower case characters too and save 8 bytes, but I think that might be going too far (that would be a huge set).